# How can I make this code not return an infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop, do-while

I think I have to use String goAgainResponse to make there not be an infinite loop but I don't know what the code for that would look like. I'm supposed to approximate pi by adding 4 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9 etc. adding as many of these terms together as the number that I ask the user to put in.

```
      int term;
      int counter = 1;
      double piCalc=0.0;
      String goAgainResponse = null;
      boolean goAgain = false;
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

      /* NOTE you may not declare any additional variables */

      do
      {

         System.out.println("This program will approximate Pi based on the following series:");
         System.out.println("4 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9 - ...");

         System.out.println("Enter the term number to which you would like to approximate Pi");

         term = kb.nextInt();
         while(term <= 9)
         {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number greater than 9:");
            term = kb.nextInt();
         }

         while(term > 9)
         {
            term += 1;
            piCalc = 4/(2 * term - 1);
            System.out.print(piCalc);
         }

         System.out.print("Would you like to try again (yes/no)? ");
     }while(goAgain);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(term <= 9)
     {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number greater than 9:");
        term = kb.nextInt();
     }
```

In this you are saying term should be greater than 9. But your in your second loop condition is term>9 and you are adding values in term, thats why the second loop is infinte

```
while(term > 9)
     {
        term += 1;
        piCalc = 4/(2 * term - 1);
        System.out.print(piCalc);
     }
```

changing the condition of 2nd loop would resolve your problem. OR
consider `term+=1` again.

Also as per @Scary Wombat, value of `boolean doagain` is never set

Answer (score 0):

`boolean goAgain = false;`

This is never set to anything else, and the loop only loops while it is `true`